# Qt Application crashes in Windows Server 2008, running fine in Windows server 2003

Tags: windows, qt, ntdll

The crash details point to ntdll.dll 
When I searched on the internet, I see a lot of application problems reported in Windows 20008 Server because of this dll.
My Windows Server 2008 machine is updated with latest packs and updates.
Is this is OS problem or my application which is buggy?

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name:    Client.exe
  Application Version:    1.3.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    51cbcdde
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version:    6.0.6002.18541
  Fault Module Timestamp:    4ec3e3d5
  Exception Code:    c0000005
  Exception Offset:    000665c9
  OS Version:    6.0.6002.2.2.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1:    ccc2
  Additional Information 2:    0a07f28ebf2977f2668fa7213522081c
  Additional Information 3:    1ac0
  Additional Information 4:    79391a57c1698c1550ee327c075e511e
```